# Azure Pipeline - Build C++ libraries that depend on eachother

Tags: visual-c++, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a solution that has a few projects.

- BaseLib
- MidLib
- TopLib

The `BaseLib` and `MidLib` are both dependencies of `TopLib`.

I want to create a single pipeline that builds these libraries in order and can find their dependency within the Azure Pipeline.

The issue I currently have is `TopLib` cannot open input file 'BaseLib.lib'

`##[error]LINK(0,0): Error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'BaseLib.lib'`

This error is pretty self explanatory but within my Pipeline I build the project successfully, copy the files to a release folder which I then use the path for `AdditionalLibraryDirectories`.

DevOps Pipelines is something that I am only just starting to pick up. So any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

**YAML** Here is the YAML that I am using. Reminder I am only starting out so I am not 100% sure how this file should look.

`Ignore the .NET installments & Nuget Install. They will be required for the applications that need to be built after making this succeed.`

```
trigger:
- azure-pipelines-second

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  #solution: '**/*.sln'
  solution: 'Main Project.sln'
  releaseDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Release'
  baseLibProject: 'BaseLib/BaseLib.vcxproj'
  MidLibProject: 'MidLib/MidLib.vcxproj'
  TopLibProject: 'TopLib/TopLib.vcxproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
#Installments
- script: choco install netfx-4.8 # .NET Framework
- script: choco install windows-sdk-10-version-1903-all # Windows SDK

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build BaseLib'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(baseLibProject)'
    platform: 'x86' # Adjust this based on your target platform
    configuration: 'Release'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 /p:AdditionalLibraryDirectories=$(releaseDir)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy BaseLib Build Output'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/BaseLib/Release'
    Contents: '**/*'
    TargetFolder: '$(releaseDir)'

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build MidLib'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(MidLibProject)'
    platform: 'x86' # Adjust this based on your target platform
    configuration: 'Release'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 /p:AdditionalLibraryDirectories=$(releaseDir)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy MidLib Build Output'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MidLib/Release'
    Contents: '**/*'
    TargetFolder: '$(releaseDir)'

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'TopLib'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(TopLibProject)'
    platform: 'x86' # Adjust this based on your target platform
    configuration: 'Release'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x86 /p:AdditionalLibraryDirectories=$(releaseDir)'
```

I tried adding the copy of the built files to a directory that the other projects can access for Additional Libraries but it did't work as expected. I was hoping the project that requires a certain library could look into the "Release" folder, see it's there and use it was a dependency.

Comment: Is there reason why you don't just have all 3 library projects in the same solution (.sln), and set the build dependencies there? They you just need your pipeline to build the solution, and let msbuild handle the build order based on the stipulated dependencies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2022

Comment: So they are part of the same solution. But when I tried to build using the build settings of the solution, it was going on a tangent and building in a completely different order. Maybe I was doing something wrong in the pipeline YAML.

Comment: Verify your build scenario outside the pipeline, by building the solution from the commandline by invoking msbuild on the .sln. Add the /bl switch to the command line arguments so that msbuild will generate an msbuild.binlog. You can readily evaluate everything msbuild did during the solution build with the log viewer at https://msbuildlog.com. When you have the command line build figured out, all  you need your pipeline to do is build the solution with args similar to what you use on the command line.